# Twitter Bootstrap Popover and Tooltip on same element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tooltip and a popover on the same element at different times:

```
$("#myDiv").tooltip({trigger:'manual',title:'foo'})
  .popover({trigger:'manual'});
```

The above works, except for the tooltip `title`. The `title` attribute of `#myDiv` in the html overrides the `title` I set in the JS. Although that's [what the docs say](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips-usage), I need to override bootstrap to use my own title for the tooltip. How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to set the `title` in the JS for `.popover` and remove `title` from the HTML.